# Regex to match date and time

Tags: python, regex

I'm creating a regex to match date and time from a string. The string is

"Giao bóng lúc 01:00 Ngày 20/02/2015"

and I want to extract the date and the time.

I create the regex to extract the date:

```
date_match = re.search(r'(\d+/\d+/\d+)',a['title'])
date = date_match.group(1)
```

The output now is: "20/02/2015"
I need also to have in another variable "01:00"

How can I expand it to get also time with one string?

Comment: Do add expected Output

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex for date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794069/regex-for-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if time and date are always the third last and last elements:

```
s = "Giao bóng lúc 01:00 Ngày 20/02/2015"
spl = s.rsplit(None,3)
tme, dte = spl[-3], spl[-1]
print(tme, dte) 
01:00 20/02/2015
```

If they are you can see just splitting is a more efficient:

```
In [33]: %%timeit
m = matcher.match(line)
m.group(1), m.group(2)
   ....: 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.08 µs per loop

In [35]: %%timeit                                    
spl = line.split()
tme, dte = spl[-3], spl[-1]
   ...: 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 354 ns per loop
```

Comment: Your measurements are little tricky :) Because you compare splitting and not compiled regexp. I sure that compilation takes most part of time.

Comment: @Jimilian, it is still going to be a lot faster

Comment: On my Mac: 0,976 µs per loop (splitting) vs 1.13 µs per loop (compilted match).

Comment: @Jimilian, not sure what you are timing it with but still almost 3 times slower on my machine

Comment: Cool. Now I know that I have very slow splitting :(

Comment: @Jimilian, how did you time it and on which version of python?

Comment: jim$ ipython --version
`1.1.0`
jim$ python --version
`Python 2.7.6`

I copy-pasted yours and mine solutions to ipython. And timed it with timeit.

Answer (score 3):

Use `re.findall` function to return a list of matched strings. In regex `{n}` called range quantifier which repeats the previous token exactly n times. `{n,m}` repeats the previous token from `n` to `m` times. Here we used the first form, `\d{4}` which matches exactly 4 digit characters. `\b` called word boundary which matches between a word character and a non-word character.

```
>>> s = "Giao bóng lúc 01:00 Ngày 20/02/2015"
>>> re.findall(r'\b\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\b|\b\d{2}:\d{2}\b', s)
['01:00', '20/02/2015']
```

You could use  `re.search` function only if you know the position of time, date substrings.

```
>>> re.search(r'\b(\d{2}:\d{2})\b.*?\b(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})\b', s).group(1)
'01:00'
>>> re.search(r'\b(\d{2}:\d{2})\b.*?\b(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})\b', s).group(2)
'20/02/2015'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.*`. It means **any symbols**. If all lines looks like example line, this code will works:

```
import re
matcher = re.compile(r".* (\d{2}:\d{2}) .* (\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2})")

m = matcher.match(line)
if m:
   print m.group(1). m.group(2)
```